# woocommerce nutrition calculation based on user selections

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a good plugin that will display the number of Calories, fat, carbs and protein when a user selects options in a woocommerce product page.  I'm looking for something similar like this: https://www.bodyfuelfoods.com/product/ground-turkey/

My client's website has the option where users can choose a protein and a side.
For the protein, they can either choose a 6oz or an 8oz portion in a dropdown select menu.
For the sides, They can choose to have 1veggie/1 carb, 2 carbs, or 2 veggies and then they would choose the specific side in another dropdown menu.

So for example:
I choose a 6oz salmon with 2 carbs.  My 2 carbs I selected are brown rice and pasta.

What I'm looking for is an easy way where I can calculate the total number of calories, protein, fat and carbs info based on the sides they choose from and the portion size.

Is there a plugin that will do this sort of thing?

Comment: Did you find any good plugins?